# Passing Class/Instance Function as a Parameter in a Function

Tags: c#

**In C# is it possible to pass a class function(not static) as a parameter in a function?**

For some reason I get a compile error inside the function download because I am passing a 'class/instance' function as the parameter.

For example:

```
public class MyPlane {
   Texture texture;

   virtual public void OnDownloadPlaneCallBack(WWW www) {
      // perform custom actions when/if file downloads correctly
      texture = www.texture;
   }

   virtual public void download() {
       Downloader.download("www.blah.com", OnDownloadPlaneCallBack);  // this gives a compile error? 
   }
}

public class Downloader {

    public static IEnumerator download(string url, Delegate callback) {
        WWW www = new WWW(url); 

        while(!www.isDone)
            yield return www;

         if (www.isDone) {
            callback.DynamicInvoke(www);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: `virtual public OnDownloadPlaneCallBack` should be `virtual public void OnDownloadPlaneCallBack`.

Comment: Use `Action<WWW>` for the callback. Also, the `if` check after the loop isn't required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can construct delegates from instance methods: that is a very powerful feature. The problem that you are seeing has to do with a specific syntax of creating delegates - by using *method groups*.

You get a compile error because method groups (that's the official name for constructing delegates from "naked" method names) cannot be passed as parameters of "untyped" `Delegate`s.

If you change the signature of your `download` method to accept `Action<WWW>`, your code will compile correctly. You could also cast your method group explicitly, like this:

```
Downloader.download("www.blah.com", (Action<WWW>)OnDownloadPlaneCallBack);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
public string CanReceiveFunction(Func<int, string> func) {
    if (func != null) return func(5);
}

public string CanConvertIntToString(int a) {
    return "here is the result: " + a;
}

public void Main() {
    var result = CanReceiveFunction(CanConvertIntToString);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```